# new to git - understanding what is master branch

Tags: java, android, git, github

I have been asked to create an application, and told to do the following:

1. Create a public repository on GitHub. If you don't have
   an username just create one, it's free. You can pick 
   whatever name for your repo.
2. Create a branch and commit your code to it. DO NOT PUSH YOUR CODE TO THE MASTER BRANCH.
3. Think that you're writing code which could be use from your future co-workers,
   and here we believe on collective ownership
4. After finishing your app, create a pull request and send us its link. 
   We'll assign someone to review it and send any comments on how to 
   improve or fix any part.

I am totally confused about what exactly is the "master branch". My understanding is
that once i finish my application, then I check it into github, and that becomes my master
branch... is my understanding wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first create your repository, it will have a single branch called `master`. They are saying not to use that, but instead create a second branch. Use this new branch to commit your code. The master branch will therefore remain empty - i.e. zero commits.

They are then asking that you create a pull request from your second branch (with the work), into `master` (which will still be empty).

It seems that

> that once i finish my application, then I check it into github

is the source of the confusion. To properly use version control systems (such as github), you would commit periodically - when you are happy with sections of the code - rather than uploading the entire application as a single commit. In this case, they are asking that your intermediate commits are done on a branch other than `master`.

Comment: but why do they not want me to push my code into master branch? whats the purpose of leaving it empty ?

Comment: Either they want to test if you know Git branches and how to do them. Or they don't want everybody working on it to send pull requests for the same branch name "master", but a different branch name. Chances are that everybody else doing this will choose a different name than you do.

Comment: @Sven agreed. The pull request itself could be used to keep track of comments. But this does seem unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this article about a good [git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), quoted from there :

> We consider **origin/master** to be the main branch where the source code of HEAD always reflects a production-ready state.

Answer (score 0):

Start a repo on Github and then clone it to your local dev environment. Then create a new branch that isn't master using:

git checkout -b my_new_branch
(This command creates a new branch and makes it your working copy)

'git branch' will show you all the branches in your repo with a * next to your current working one.

You don't need to finish your app before committing it into your new branch. Some peoples philosophy is 'little and often'

A good GUI can help understanding how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

The master branch is the default branch, created when you first create a repository.  By default, when you check an application into github, it will go into the master branch.

On github, you can create a new branch by clicking on the branch:Master button (see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWqjG.png)), and then typing in a new name for your branch.

If you are using eclipse for your project, you can switch branches with `Team > Switch To`.  You can switch to an existing branch or create a new branch via that method.